# How to delete object from array by specific value using mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I want to check if the id exists in the `contacts` array and pull the object that contains this id using mongoose. For instance, if i get the `id - 5fe1c307330e711a6024697f`, the first object should be deleted. i gave it a try but nothing happened.
the data structure is looks like:

```
{
     _id: (id),
     contacts: [
         0: {
             _id: (id),
             id: '5fe1c307330e711a6024697f'
         }
         1: {
             _id: (id),
             id: '21412412412412412421421'
         }
}
```

And the code i've tried:

```
const { contactId, conversationId } = req.body;
const conversation = await Conversation.findById(conversationId);
const existingContacts = conversation.contacts;
existingContacts.map(existingContact => {
    if (existingContact.id === contactId) {
        let deletedContact = Conversation.findByIdAndUpdate(conversationId, {
            $pull: {
                  contacts: { id: contactId }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just simple, don't need to map, it will delete/pull `contactId`,

```
const { contactId, conversationId } = req.body;
let deletedContact = Conversation.findByIdAndUpdate(
    conversationId,
    {
        $pull: {
            contacts: { _id: contactId }
        }    
    }
);
```